# React supports crossOrigin on image attributes. But it seems doesn't work for me

Tags: image, reactjs, cross-domain, cropperjs

I use cropperjs in react:

```
<img
  crossOrigin="anonymous"
  src={this.props.sourceDataURL}
  style={{maxWidth: '100%', visibility: 'hidden'}}
  ref={this.sourceRef}
  alt="img"
/>
```

This doesn't work for cross origin images.However, when I changed 'crossOrigin' to 'crossorigin', it will work. But I got the warning:

> Warning: Unknown DOM property crossorigin. Did you mean crossOrigin?

I wonder how to use 'crossOrigin' attribute in img tab in react and cropperjs?
Here is the cropperjs library:
https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs

Comment: What version of react are you using?

Comment: I am using react 15.6.2.@Dakota

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure this is an issue with < React 16 dom attributes, I would try updating to React 16 and see if it resolves the issue.

See: https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/08/dom-attributes-in-react-16.html

Comment: Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: I believe react is supposed to support crossOrigin so it's probably whitelisted even in the new update so I'd like to know if this worked.

Comment: All React elements attributes (events included) are named using camelCase, rather than lowercase, so it's true that react support crossOrigin attribute. But cropperjs read that attribute as crossorigin. Look this issue:https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/issues/274. It's a convention problem.

Comment: Yea I figured it still wouldn't work because of that, I'm not sure you can do much about it, maybe file an issue with the React team and they can help you out.